# How do I add a VScrollBar to a textbox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using a theme from the web for my `vb.net` application and the `textbox` does not have scrollbars or a scrollbar property. The theme did come with a `VScrollBar Control`, but I don't know how to add code to it to make it scroll the textbox like normal. Can anyone help me?

These are `Custom Controls`.

`It's a Windows Form. (WinForms)`

Textbox and its Properties:

[image]

Comment: Visual Basic .Net is **not** the same as Visual Basic for Applications. Pick one, not both.

Comment: @TheBlueDog Ok thanks. did not know cause i made an application on visual basic 2010. other tags i could put?

Comment: We also need to know if this is WinForms, WPF, or ASP.NET.  Adding scrollbars is completely different on each platform.

Comment: @TheBlueDog It is a Windows Form

Comment: The textbox does not *normally* have a scrollbar, just when it is multiline

Comment: @Plutonix it is a property that you can add when its a multiline. the theme i have does not have a property for it. i need code for the VScrollBar Control so the themed multiline textbox can have one.

Comment: Can you expand on "theme from the web"?  Are you using a 3rd party control?

Comment: @JStevens no just a large script pastbin into a vb class. after a rebuild it showed the custom controls.

Comment: Your custom control is a third party control.  It sounds like it contains COM objects.  VScrollBar is a VB6 control.  You may want to rethink its use.  But if you still wish to solve this.  I would suggest changing your post to VB6 or maybe a COM interop question...

Comment: so VScrollBars are not compatible with VB 2010? then why is it in VB 2010? I still want to use it.

Comment: @cybermonkey no i know the difference between vb and vb.net just learned the difference between vb.net and vba today so im good.

Comment: Your request is very odd. You use custom controls, but everyone here assumed you didn't, since you never specified it before. Anyways, [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?743241-addinng-vscrollbar-to-textbox-user-control) is the only thing that I found.

Comment: @cybermonkey Oh you're right, sorry, I didn't read your previous comment.

Comment: @BishopBarber what code and where does it get pasted? also what is it doing?

Comment: @cybermonkey i have put a link for an image you requested.

Comment: @cybermonkey im sorry but im not emailing you the source code of my project. or are you talking about the source code of the theme?

Answer (score 6):

Vertical scroll bars can be added to `TextBox` form objects, but however they **must** be `Multiline`:

[image]

This can either be done by setting `Multiline` to `True` and `ScrollBars` to `Vertical`:

[image]

or it can be done via code, programmatically, as per se:

```
TextBox1.Multiline = True
TextBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical
```

You can set `ScrollBars` to be only horizontal, vertical, both, or none (default):

[image]

Remember, you should:

- Be sanitizing the user's input if you're sending the textbox's contents off to a database
- Limit the amount of characters that the user can input (see below)
- Be using [proper programming technique](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260844%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) by naming your objects properly, for example, try not to name your textbox `TextBox1`

As mentioned above, you may want to show the amount of characters the user can input, for example:

[image]

the code for this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    text1.MaxLength = 140
    charsLeft.Text = "0/" + CStr(text1.MaxLength)
End Sub

Private Sub textHasChanged() Handles text1.TextChanged
    charsLeft.Text = CStr(text1.TextLength) + "/" + CStr(text1.MaxLength)
End Sub
```